# File size limit for reading sharepoint file using python Office365-REST-Python-Client

Tags: python, file, sharepoint, office365, office365api

I want to read files from Sharepoint using python Office365-REST-Python-Client. What is the maximum file size that I can read? Are there any alternatives to read large files.